# javascript extended class how to access parent imported function?

Tags: javascript

I am extending a javascript class which has an import `myParseFloat`. An error is thrown that a child class does not have access to `myParseFloat`. What is the best approach to pass this function to a class extending a class? Importing the functions additionally on the child seems the easiest, but I am guessing incorrect. I would like to access myParseFloat directly, but i could use this.myParseFloat if needed.

TableView.js

```
import {myParseFloat, round2} from '../../lib/math';

export default class TableView {
    constructor(model){
        console.log(myParseFloat('1.2333445'));


    }

}
```

DataTableView.js

```
import TableView from './TableView';

export default class DataTableView extends TableView {
    constructor(model) {
        super(model);
        console.log(myParseFloat('1.2333445')); //myParseFloat is not available

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imports in javascript are exclusive to the module, so you'll need the line in both files.

Comment: dang where did you find that info? google was of no help to me.

Comment: I don't have any specific source since I don't know what module system you're using but that's a standard in most languages I'm familiar with. The idea behind *modules* is that everything is self-contained. `TableView` depends on `myParseFloat` but that doesn't mean `DataTableView` does separately. Luckily, module systems are smart and won't load it twice - they have caching, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a way to achieve this

```
import {myParseFloat, round2} from '../../lib/math';

export default class TableView {
    constructor(model){
        this.myParseFloat = myParseFloat;
        this.round2 = round2;
    }

}
```

And in child class

```
import TableView from './TableView';

export default class DataTableView extends TableView {
    constructor(model) {
        super(model);
        console.log(this.myParseFloat('1.2333445')); 
    }
}
```